# List of activities performed by JBoss in master-slave server-group startup in domain mode

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I've been trying to search the web for the order of the list of processes/activities, a JBoss EAP 6.4 Application Server performs when a server group in a master-slave configuration is restarted.

I understand from the documentation available at : [JBoss EAP 6.4 RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/about_managed_domains)
, that the configuration is shared across the group but what is the sequence of startup activities/processes ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're specifically looking for?

Comment: Hello there. Apologies for being so late. What I am looking for is a list or sequence of startup activities that JBoss performs. I asked this as I was having trouble understanding why would one master-slave environment load certain classes first and another master-slave environment loads another set of classes first.

Comment: If you're talking about class loading in general there is no specific order and it could depend on the environment.

Comment: Yeah, that could possibly explain the issue I was facing. Thanks.